# How to find child element from Json or class object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object which is holding JSON record, I want to fetch an inner child object from the JSON.

The Sample JSON is below, dbSettings is holding all the properties of this JSON.

```
{
  "Settings": [
  {
              "Category": "Bodies 0",
              "MDName": "CompleteDispensers",
              "subSettings": [
                {
                  "Category": "CompleteDispensers",
                  "MDName": "CompleteDispensers 0",
                  "subSettings": [
                    {
                      "Category": "CompleteDispensers 0",
                      "MDName": "dispenserTypeID",
                      "subSettings": null
                    },
                    {
                      "Category": "CompleteDispensers 0",
                      "MDName": "productID",
                      "subSettings": null
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Category": "CompleteDispensers",
                  "MDName": "CompleteDispensers 1",
                  "subSettings": [
                    {
                      "Category": "CompleteDispensers 1",
                      "MDName": "dispenserTypeID",
                      "subSettings": null
                    },
                    {
                      "Category": "CompleteDispensers 1",
                      "MDName": "productID",
                      "subSettings": null
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
  ]
}
```

I tried which below code, which is fetching the null record.

```
var obj = dbSettings.Settings.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Name == 
            Constants.DispenseIDName);
```

When I tried as below, I am getting the value as expected.

```
var result = itemTitle > itemTitle1 ? itemTitle : itemTitle1;

if (dbSettings.Settings[9].subSettings[0].subSettings[14].Name == 
        Constants.DispenseIDName)
            {
                dbSettings.Settings[9].subSettings[0].subSettings[14].Value = 
                 result.ToString();
            }
```

I want this code to be dynamic. Instead of using the index value

Settings[9].subSettings[0].subSettings[14], I want this to be queried with the class object using Linq or any other way to find the inner child object in c#.

As suggested, I tried and getting a null reference exception.

```
 if (dbSettings.Settings.SelectMany(x => x.subSettings)!=null)
            {
                if (dbSettings.Settings.SelectMany(x => x.subSettings).SelectMany(x => x.subSettings) != null)
                {
                    if (dbSettings.Settings.SelectMany(x => x.subSettings).SelectMany(x => x.subSettings).Any(x => x.Name == Constants.DispenseIDName))
                    {
                        dbSettings.Settings.SelectMany(x => x.subSettings).SelectMany(x => x.subSettings).Any(x => x.Value == result.ToString() );
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here, for the all inner record, we don't have data in the subsetting. So I kept the null check condition and tried, but its throwing null reference exception.

Any Suggestion !!

Comment: To begin with, it would be great if you could share a sample Json

Comment: did you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045782/using-linq-to-select-into-an-object-with-children-from-json ?

Comment: What's the type of dbSettings?

Comment: I have added the Sample JSON in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbSettings.SelectMany(x=>xSettings).SelectMany(x=>x.subSettings).SelectMany(x=>x.subSettings).Any(x=>x.Name == Constants.DispenseIDName);
```

This will return true if any of the name are equal the required one.

Example nested int list:

```
List<List<List<List<int>>>> myMegaList = new List<List<List<List<int>>>>(){
new List<List<List<int>>>{
new List<List<int>>{
new List<int>{
2,4,5,6,7
}
}
}

};

myMegaList.SelectMany(x=>x).SelectMany(x=>x).SelectMany(x=>x).Any(x=>x==2);
```

Comment: You have to debug and see where your reference is null at this point.

Comment: Thanks !! I tried as per the suggestion, but getting a null reference exception.